# Affect of Angular Guard within lazy loaded feature module with service providedIn: 'root'

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module, lazy-loading, guard

Ok, let's imagine I have `AppRoutingModule` where I declare routes with lazy loading modules, then I need for at least one route to use a guard for example `CanDeactivate`. This guard is placed in one of the feature modules and it uses service for validation, which is in the same module.

So when I run the code, I obviously got `nullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[guard-> service-> service-> service]`, so I decided to use `providedIn: 'root'` in the `@Injectable` in that service, which solved my problem, but I'm not sure is that somehow affect lazy loading ?

**So the question is:**
Does `providedIn: 'root'` affect lazy loading. Will it remain "lazy" loading or it will load immediately ?

Edit:

Route inside AppRouting looks like:

```
{
    path: PATHS.appointmentsCall,
    canDeactivate: [InterruptGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('some path').then((m) => m.CallModule),
},
```

Guard in the CallModule looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InterruptGuard implements CanDeactivate<unknown> {
    constructor(private readonly facade: CallFacade) {}
    ...
}
```

CallFacade be like:

```
 @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class CallFacade { 
        ... 
    }
```

Comment: Lazy loading will not affect by providedIn root, for service when you add `providedIn: 'root'` then you have one instance of the service throughout the app inside lazy loading too!

Comment: Where is that service provided before you added providedIn: 'root' in service?  And one more important question is, is that module where service is provided loaded lazily?

Comment: That service was provided right in the FeatureModule which was lazy loaded, and answer to the second question - yes.

well, let me edit question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All eagerly loaded modules share their `RootInjector`(`AppModule` in simple terms). When you provide a service using `@Injectable` annotation together with `providedIn: 'root'` is like you added it to `AppModule` `providers` array. One instance of that service will be available throughout application.

Adding `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` to your service won't mess your lazily loaded module. If the service is only used within a lazy loaded module it will be lazy loaded with that module, otherwise it will be provided as soon application is bootstraped. That service is provided in `RootInjector`.

It is logical that in this case it won't throw an NullInjector error, which is the last stop where Angular tries to resolve a dependency and there eventually throws an error.

*Additional info*: when you use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` services are tree shakeable and this is the best practice in general since it reduces bundle size of an application.

Per https://juristr.com/blog/2021/04/angular-di-and-lazy-modules/
[image]